# validación con expresiones regulares javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo la siguiente expresión regular para validar una dirección por ejemplo `carrera 3 ## 7c -26`. El problema es que al validar el carácter `[-]`, el número siguiente no lo toma como obligatorio, si no que deja pasar cualquier tipo letra numero símbolo etc, incluso se puede dejar el espacio vacío.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el carácter después de `[-]` sea obligatorio?

Gracias por la ayuda

```
const pattern = /^[CarreraCraCrCalleCllCllecarreracracrcallecllclle]+\s?\d{0,300}\s?[#][#]\s?\d{0,300}\s?\D?\s?[-]\s?\d{0,300}/;
```

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: ¿Por que usas `[CarreraCraCrCalleCllCllecarreracracrcallecllclle]`? Con que pongas 1 sola vez cada caracter alcanza

Comment: Está claro que ese `CarreraCraCrCalleCll...` también valida como correctos `llC`, `ll`, `CCCCCCCCC` y cualquier combinación de esas letras, ¿no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin ponerse a pensar mucho en ese grupo inicial, la solución es que le digas que el último grupo debe tener al menos una ocurrencia

```
^[CcLlRrAaEe]+\s?\d{0,300}\s?[#][#]\s?\d{0,300}\s?\D?\s?[-]\s?\d{1,300}
```

Puedes apoyarte en [regExr](https://regexr.com/) para validarlo y mejorarlo. Te va explicando la expresión parte por parte.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Nota:** Ese segmento `[CarreraCraCrCalleCllCllecarreracracrcallecllclle]+` realmente va a validar que una de esas letras `Carelc` esté al menos una vez. Por eso, un valor `CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC 12 ## 1-1` hará match.

Si, de pura casualidad, quisieras limitar *un poquito* las opciones de nombre de calle, *podrías* usar `\b`

```
^\b(calle|Calle|cll|Cll|Cra|cra|carrera|Carrera)\s?\d{0,300}\s?[#][#]\s?\d{0,300}\s?\D?\s?[-]\s?\d{1,300}
```